# How to open a database outside app storage in Android 11

Tags: android, database

Android is making it very difficult to access app storage (Android/data/xxx). I have been able to get around that for most files, but not a database. I have found no way for an app to open a database unless it is in the apps app storage.

Many applications on many OS's can open and use Sqlite databases. I intend for the database to usable elsewhere and don't want it to be lost if the app is uninstalled. I also want it available for backup, and I want it to be transferable to another device.

If the user wants to delete it fine, but I don't want it deleted out from under them.

I can store and use other files using the Storage Access Framework in places they are accessible by the user and will remain if the app is uninstalled. I have found no way to open a database from such a location though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can go with a backup/restore or import/export metaphor. Have the "real" database be in some place where you have full read/write filesystem access (e.g., `getFilesDir()`), and use the Storage Access Framework for working with external copies of the data. See [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/tree/vFINAL/ImportExport) (profiled in [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Room)).

Comment: The real database apparently has to be in app storage. I'm working on save/restore options in the app to an SAF location, probably the best solution. I downloaded the book on Room and will look at it. I like the KISS principle and prefer to avoid that kind of solution, though. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: "The real database apparently has to be in app storage" -- it has to be somewhere where you have direct read/write filesystem access. That pretty much means what you are referring to as app storage.

Comment: No, I can read/write files lots of places that don't go away when the app is uninstalled and which can be copied to other devices. I save my databases there, but the working database has to be in app storage. I have found no way to open a database from those others. It has to be done with a conventional File, not with a Uri. I am using SQLiteOpenHelper, the standard way. I don't see any way to do it using the SQLiteDatsbase either.

Comment: To be clear, by "app storage" I mean getExternalFilesDir.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must understand some basic concepts such  as

1. App-specific storage
2. Shared storage
3. Preferences and
4. Databases (how android make use of it).

kindly read the below documentation carefully for proper understanding
[read the documentation carefully](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)